# Getting parent/child process id from a specific process id

Tags: process

I'm trying to get a name of a process given its process id along with its children, parent and grandparent names.

I've used `ps -eo` for getting the name of the process id, but not not for any of its children, parents or grandparents.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

`pstree -pls your_pid`

> **pstree** - display a tree of processes.
>
> - **-p** Show PIDs. PIDs are shown as decimal numbers in parentheses after each process name.
> - **-s** Show parent processes of the specified process.
> - **-l** Display long lines. By default, lines are truncated to either the COLUMNS environment variable or the display width.

Answer (score 1):

To get a process name, given its pid:

```
pid=42
ps -o comm= -p $pid
```

To get the names of the child processes of a given pid (Linux procps):

```
ps -o comm= --ppid $pid
```

To get the names of the child processes of a given pid (POSIX):

```
for cpid in $(ps -eo pid=,ppid= | awk -v pid=$pid '$2==pid{print $1}'); do ps -o comm= -p $cpid; done
```

To get the name of the parent process of a given pid:

```
ps -o comm= -p $(ps -o ppid= -p $pid)
```

To get the name of the grandparent process of a given pid (assuming you haven't hit your init system yet):

```
ps -o comm= -p $(ps -o ppid= -p $(ps -o ppid= -p $pid))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get a list of child process IDs using the following command:

```
pgrep -P $parent_pid
```

Credit to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17743940/5774498).

Comment: This does not seem to do what the user asks for. which is to get the parent process, the child process(es) and grandchildren process(es) of a given process.